# TypeScript. Как проверить является ли входящий параметр функции прототипом определенного класса?

Tags: ооп, typescript

Я пытаюсь создать функцию, которая должна принемать класс (не инстанс класса), который должен быть прототипом базового класса (`Base`). Когда я пытаюсь узать тип входящего параметра функции как `Base`, то получаю TypeScript ошибку. Как правильно указать тип входящего параметра функиции `combine`?

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract name(): string
}

class SimpleClass extends Base {
  name() {
    return 'Name'
  }
}

function combine(someClass: Base) {
  return {
    className: someClass,
  }
}

// Получаю TypeScript ошибку
combine(SimpleClass)
```

TypeScript error

```
TS2345: 
Argument of type 'typeof SimpleClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Base'.
Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
```

Comment: `someClass: typeof Base`

Comment: Но всё таки не «прототипом», а наоборот «наследником» или «расширением». Это Base является прототипом для SimpleClass.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал это следующим образом

> Простите, а зачем вам столько галоперидола...

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract name(): string
}

class SimpleClass extends Base {
  name() {
    return 'Name'
  }
}

const combine = <T extends Base>(someClass: new () => T) => ({
  className: someClass,
});

combine(SimpleClass)
```